# Notice: Undefined property:

Tags: magento2, fatal-error

I am new here.

My client just sent me magento2 mega menu extention for setup and manage their menu and I installed it on their website but after installation their website gone down.

according to megamenu provider documentation I installed activation with the following commands.

first I run: `php bin/magento cache:disable`

Then I uploaded files and after files uploaded i run this command:
`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

then I run this command: php bin/magento cache:enable

after installation website gone down.

I'm getting this error

> Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined property: Magezon\NinjaMenus\Block\TopMenu\Interceptor::$_helper in /mnt/data/home/202257.cloudwaysapps.com/tzpdyygggw/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php on line 110

Please provide me solution for this how to fix line 110 or how to bypass this error.

Waiting for reply.

Comment: Can you please provide more information like which magento version you are working and please also check the extension compatibility with the current magento version
Thanks

Comment: compile the code to get this error resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the following

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile

bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

bin/magento indexer:reindex

bin/magento cache:flush
```